# Is there a way to output the value in one column based on two others?

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create output for one column in my table by basing it off of the values in two other columns.

I've tried working with the variables and think I have gotten the loop to work. The issues I keep running into are "Mismatch" and "Global"

```
Private Sub formatcolumnF()

Dim eqa As Range, eqt As Range

Set eqa = ActiveSheet.Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown))
Set eqt = ActiveSheet.Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))

Dim result As String, Cell As Range

For Each Cell In eqa
     If Cell >= eqt.Value + 0.025 Then
            result = "OVER"
     ElseIf Cell <= eqt.Value - 0.025 Then
            result = "UNDER"
     ElseIf Cell <= eqt.Value + 0.025 Or Cell >= eqt.Value - 0.025 Then
            result = "ON TARGET"
     Else
            result = ""
     End If
Next Cell

Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown)).Value = result

End Sub
```

I expect the output in column F to be one of the string results. When I run it for a specific row in the table the code works but when I try to run it for the whole column it does not.

Comment: `eqt` is a range and therfore one cannot equate a full range to one cell.  You will need another loop to loop the second range as well.

Comment: Your understanding of how to reference cells when using a For Each loop is incorrect with respect to your use of eqt.  The for each only relates to eqa.  You will be better served by reading the two ranges into VBA arrays and then iterating over the arrays from Lbound to Ubound.

Comment: You don't need VBA for this, Excel functions are sufficient.

Comment: It may be easier to read these ranges into an array, like `arr_a = ActiveSheet.Range("D2", ActiveSheet.Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Value2` and `arr_t` similarly. Then, you can `Dim i As Integer` and do your loop over the values of `arr_a` and `arr_t` with `For i = LBound(arr_a, 1) To UBound(arr_a,1)`  and `If arr_a(i, 1) >= arr_t(i, 1) Then` blah blah

Comment: @jessi So how exactly would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

```
Private Sub FormatcolumnF()

    Dim eqa As Range, eqt As Range

    Set eqa = ActiveSheet.Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown))
    Set eqt = ActiveSheet.Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))

    Dim result As String, Cell As Range

    For Each Cell In eqa.Cells
        If IsNumeric(Cell) Then
            If Cell.Value >= Application.Sum(eqt.Value) + 0.025 Then
                Cells(Cell.Row, "F") = "OVER"
            ElseIf Cell <= Application.Sum(eqt.Value) - 0.025 Then
                Cells(Cell.Row, "F") = "UNDER"
            ElseIf Cell <= Application.Sum(eqt.Value) + 0.025 _
            Or Cell >= Application.Sum(eqt.Value) - 0.025 Then
                Cells(Cell.Row, "F") = "ON TARGET"
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

The problem in the code was mainly that `eqt.Value` does not return value, because the `eqt` range is multiple cells. Thus, `Application.Sum(eqt.Value)` should be used. Furthermore, I have added an additional check for whether the cell is numeric in the loop here - `If IsNumeric(Cell) Then`. At the end, with the CElls(Cell.Row, "F") the corresponding cell in row "F" is updated with OVER and UNDER. The code could be improved further, with avoiding `ActiveSheet` and declaring the sheet, on which is worked. Take a look at the dots, before `Range` and `Cells`, they refer to the worksheet in the `With`.

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub FormatcolumnF()

    Dim eqa As Range, eqt As Range
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 
    'or even better by name like "Worksheets(Table1)"

    With wks
        Set eqa = .Range("D2", .Range("D2").End(xlDown))
        Set eqt = .Range("C2", .Range("C2").End(xlDown))
    End With

    Dim result As String, cell As Range

    With wks
        For Each cell In eqa.Cells
            If IsNumeric(cell) Then
                If cell.Value >= Application.Sum(eqt.Value) + 0.025 Then
                    .Cells(cell.Row, "F") = "OVER"
                ElseIf cell <= Application.Sum(eqt.Value) - 0.025 Then
                    .Cells(cell.Row, "F") = "UNDER"
                ElseIf cell <= Application.Sum(eqt.Value) + 0.025 _
                    Or cell >= Application.Sum(eqt.Value) - 0.025 Then
                    .Cells(cell.Row, "F")  = "ON TARGET"
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: So the first snippet of code works partially as right now I am getting "Under" for every cell when they are not all under. The second snippet of code gives me a 1004 error.

Comment: @tonytwotime - change `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` to `ActiveSheet` in the second snippet. Where is the error, btw?

Comment: it is in this line `.Cells(cell.Row, "F").Text = "UNDER"` prior to that it was in the line `.Cells(cell.Row, "F").Text = "ON TARGET"`

Comment: @tonytwotime - I removed the `.Text` part. Now it should be working.

Comment: Even with the changes it is still outputting only "UNDER" in column F

Comment: @tonytwotime - the condition is this one - `Application.Sum(eqt.Value) - 0.025`, Are you sure it is not the input? Try "walking" step-by-step with F8 and see the corresponding values.